# Как проверить, есть ли в списке определённое число?

Tags: python

Нужно проверить есть ли число 2 в списке: "3, 4, 21, 22, 23"
Пробовал:

```
async def check1():
    list1 = "3, 4, 21, 22, 23"
    check = "2"
    if list1.find(check) != -1:
        print("число 2 найдено!")
    else:
        print("2 не найдено")
```

Однако получаю в ответ "число 2 найдено"

Подскажите пожалуйста, что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: фактически `list1` у вас строка, а так будет список: `list1.split(', ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, с помощью регулярных выражений:

```py
import re

async def check1():
    list1 = "3, 4, 21, 22, 23"
    check = "2"
    rx = re.compile('\d+')         # <- добавлено
    if check in rx.findall(list1): # <- изменено
        print("число 2 найдено!")
    else:
        print("2 не найдено")
```

Здесь я ищу все числа в строке с помощью шаблона `\d+` и проверяю, что среди этих чисел есть искомое.